# Firefox Error While running python script on remote server(pythonanywhere)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am trying to run a python script. But I am constantly getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import csv
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
today = date.today()
date_today = today.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")
file_name = 'marchon-stock-update-'+date_today+'.csv'
my_file = open(file_name, 'w')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path of geckodriver.exe')
```

This is the error:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile object at 
0x7fb982ea25e0>Traceback (most recent call last): File 
"/home/........./marchon.py", line 16, in <module> browser = 
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/path of geckodriver.exe') File 
"/usr/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 79, in     
__init__ executor = ExtensionConnection("127.0.0.1", self.profile, 
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 
52, in __init__ self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, 
timeout=timeout) File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in 
launch_browser self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout) File 
"/usr/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 98, in 
_wait_until_connectable raise 
WebDriverException(selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. 
If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check 
it for details.
```

This error is does not happen when I am running the script locally. How can I overcome this error?

Comment: What is the real value of `executable_path` provided to `webdriver.Firefox()`? The one you have obviously won't work. Besides, it's advised to use headless Chrome instead of Firefox on PythonAnywhere -- see: [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/selenium/)

Comment: obviously this is not the actual path. C:\Users\dd\anaconda3 is the path on my local machine, 
/home/user/geckodriver.exe is the path on pythonanywhere server.

Comment: ok so i have tried using headless chrome, but it is not opening ....and I am getting errors unable to locate the elements.

Comment: browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/")
    print(browser.page_source) When I print it, page source is not being shown using headless chrome. That means it is not opening on chrome browser. I get this page source: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>, which is definitely not a required page source.

Comment: Are you on a paid account? Free accounts are restricted to the whitelisted domains (usually public APIs).

Comment: Oh ok...no I'm not a paid account.

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what's in the response you're getting (the commenting system appears to have trimmed it in your comment above) but if you are being limited by the free account thing, it will say something about that in the response you're getting.